# Does my associated ASM Instance have any play in Re-naming my SID?

Tags: oracle

Greetings DBA Experts,

I have changed my Oracle SID in the past by updating the init.ora file, and updating
my environment (vars, tns, lintener, etc..), yet not since we moved to 11g with ASM. 
I come from an app development team, and when I ask our system-level DBA's the best way to do this, they just reply with "Why would you want to do that?".
Is there anything extra or different I need to do in renaming a SID with respect to our ASM instance?
Thanks very much!

Comment: I'll ask the same question as your DBAs. Why do you want to rename it? Are you taking a production copy or something?

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for your reply... we have dev, qa, and production instances.  All the have the "prod_db" sid.  We would like to have the dev SID represent dev like "dev_db" and qa like "qa_db".  The DB name can remain the same, just looking for a way to represent each instance uniquely.

Comment: Understood. You can do this with different tns names - saves the hassle of renaming. Having said that I know first-hand how dangerous it is having non-prod DBs with the same name as prod DBs.

Answer (score 2):

[This blog post](http://oracleinstance.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/rename-rac-database.html) shows you the required steps. I'd think long & hard before doing so, though as recreating control files is not something to betaken lightly. You don't need to do anything with the +ASM instance.

Answer (score 2):

When you just want to rename the ORACLE_SID there is no extra work to be done than you already did

> (vars, tns, lintener, etc..)

The fiddling with controlfile is only needed when you want to rename the database, what not is what you want. In you case ASM does not change anything for you.

Comment: Great, thanks for chiming in on the ASM factor!